# Подключение jQuery к html

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь подключить jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>lll</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cute+Font|Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Но так сделать не получается, вот сообщение:

> There is no locally stored library for the HTTP link. less... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) 
>   Inspection info: Checks that URL of an external JavaScript library is associated with a locally stored file used for code completion and navigation. Use 'Download library' quick fix (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to solve the problem.

Comment: Скопировал ваш код. Запустил. Всё ок. Проверьте тип сохранённого файла. И да, вы подключаете `D3`!

Comment: Что значит D3 ?

Comment: Библиотека, https://d3js.org/

Answer (score 2):

В шапку вставь и будет работать `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" />`

Answer (score 0):

Вы пользуете 146% WebStorm (или IDE на его базе), а он не любит, когда подключают удалённо библиотеки (а это зло). Делает он так от того, чтобы у вас гарантированно работала библиотека и не отваливалась при недоступности API.